# Using javascript for checking forms

Tags: javascript, html, regex

here is my code:

```
<script>
    function check(){
        var error = '';
        var name = document.forms['form1'].name.value;
        var age = document.forms['form1'].age.value;

        var checkname = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$");
        var checkage = new RegExp("^[1-9]{1}+[0-9]{1}$");

        if (!checkname.test(name)) error+= 'Blad w nameniu\n';
        if (!checkage.test(age)) error+= 'Blad w ageu\n';

        if (error == '')
            return true;
        else {
            alert(error);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="form1">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p>Age: <input type="text" name="age"></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="check()">Send</button>
</form>
```

I have no idea why the given code simply doesn't work. There is no action at all. I have tried to change `<button>` to `<input type="sumbit">` and `<form onSubmit="check()">` but had no luck.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQ54h/)

Comment: could you add a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: By no action, do you mean the form doesn't submit, the JavaScript doesn't run, or both?  Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: In my opinion JS doesn't run at all.
I don't think I can use console

Comment: If the JavaScript doesn't work correctly, it means that there is most likely an error in the console.  What is the error?  Also, what is it not doing that it should be?  Is it submitting the form when it shouldn't or not submitting the form when it should?

Comment: Ok, just discovered the JS console in Chrome. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm hopeless at regexes, so I cant help much but the javascript doesn't like yours so thats where you need to start debugging

Comment: Without checking, are you sure `document.forms['form1'].name` will pick up a control with `name="name"`... wouldn't it be looking for `id="name"`?

Comment: @andrew The main problem was '+' in second regex. It is working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the regular expression for checkage

```
var checkage = new RegExp("^[1-9]{1}+[0-9]{1}$");
```

this needs to be

```
 var checkage = new RegExp("^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$");
```

And  you can use firebug for firefox ( is a free add-on that helps you a lot).

Have a good day.

Comment: It can be even simpler... `/^[1-9][0-9]$/`... having `{1}` is pointless

Comment: Yes,Thank you, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is the checkage regular expression. Instead of this :

```
var checkage = new RegExp("^[1-9]{1}+[0-9]{1}$");
```

You could try :

```
var checkage = new RegExp("/(^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|^100$)/");
```

But IMHO, regex is not the good way to validate the age. You should just write a simple function which check if the number is in between 0 - 100 range

Hope this helps !